# Write-through cache Redis

Tags: java, caching, redis, apache-kafka

I have been poundering on how to reliably implement a write-through caching mechanism to store realtime data.

Basically what we need is this:

```
Save data to Redis -> Save to database (underlying)  
Read data from Redis <- Read from database in case unavailable in cache
```

The resources online to help in the implementation of this caching strategy seem scarce.

The problem is:

1) No built-in transaction possibility between Redis and the database (Mongo in my case).
2) No transactions mean that writes to the underlying database are unreliable.

The most straightforward way I see how this can be implemented is by using a broker like Kafka and putting messages on a persistent queue to be processed later.
Therefore Kafka would be the responsible entity for reliable processing.

Another way would be by having a custom implementation in a scheduler that checks the Redis database for dirty records. On first thought there seem to be some tradeoffs to this approach and I would like not having to go this road if possible.

I am looking on some options on how this can be implemented otherwise.
Or whether this is in fact the most viable approach.

Comment: why not to write to db first? Usual practice is to write in db first and then when u read from it -> create cache, when delete/update entity -> invalidate cache on this key. Because you get more read operations than write. And do you use Redis with AOF? Don't think that its much faster at write than Mongo.

Comment: @ipave if the write to database or the invaidation comes first depends on the level of data consistency he needs.

Comment: @ipave That doesn't work for me. As I'm working with live data, it would require a retrieval from the database on every request to fill the cache, eliminating the advantage of using the cache.

Comment: @Alexandar Petrov I'm talking about new record(no cache yet created). If u edit or delete record best is to delete cahe and than delete record. Because if u delete cache and u process is dead - worst case is u read from db again its better than u delete record and cahe is not deleted. And that way u get inconsistant state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So better approach than is as u mentioned above is to use kafka and consumer which will store data to mongo. But read about it delivery guarantee, as i remember exactly once is guaranteed in kafka streams only (between two topics), in your case your database should be idempotent because u get at least once guarantee. And don't forget to turn AOF on with Redis, not to loose data. And don't forget that in this case u get eventual consistency in db with all the consequences.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there no other way? I can't find any good resource on write-through implementations other than theoretical reads. The other thing is that my consumer still needs some custom code to manage failing writes on the database in this case.

Comment: Its not a usual task, and i'm pretty shure that write to mongo is not much faster than to Redis with AOF, so maybe its better approach to write to db first.  Or just leave only one storage. Did you check this approach and faced some perfomance problems? Maybe it's enough perfomance with only mongo and you do advance optimization?

Comment: And if you have some constraints in mongo it'll be a nigthtmare...so i don't recomend to act this way. Better have only one db or write to db first and read from cache...

Comment: Yes but as I explained, I cannot read from cache after saving to the db. It is about live data that needs to be readily available in the cache and up to date at any time. I will not make a db request on every retrieval requested by the client to check and fill up the cache if needed. The reason why I want a distributed cache, is because data will grow exponentially (live feeds will be added per google place), and this typically will result in decreased performance over time using a standard database. This is why it made sense for me to use the cache as primary and avoid future headache.

Comment: Then use this approach with kafka, but be ready for mistakes caused by constraints, because untill you check constraint you are not sure about you data. And y'll make calculation under unchecked data. So this way as far as i understand you get two options: 1) fast mechansim with possible mistakes 2) slow mechanism with no mistakes. If you system allows mistakes then take 1.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I don't want user data to get lost. I'm currently looking into 2 phase commits; perhaps this could be a viable alternative and is pretty common.

Comment: 2pc will be much slower than this both approaches. And No magic exist it's usuall CAP theorem problem (U are having 2 states in both storages). And i never seen this mechanism for Redis. You'll have to implement it yourself.

Comment: You gave option 1) fast with mistakes, 2) slow without mistakes. Sounds like 3) slow upload, but reliable and fast retrieval. It concerns appending post data to cache and nosql, so I couldn't imagine it to be that slow... Also I don't see how this would lead to inconsistent state. Do share your thought if you think otherwise

Answer (score 0):

On review I will use MongoDB as a single datastore without Redis at all.
Premature optimization is evil I guess.

Anyhow, I can add additional architecture afterwards after benchmarking.
Plans to refactor towards a cache shouldn't be too hard.

Scaling is additional concern so I shouldn't be bothered with that during development right now.

Accepted @Ipave answer, going with a single datastore for the moment.